# Retrieve rows that their SUM is less than a column in joined table

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm not sure if this is possible or even smart but here goes:

I have 2 tables, one that is a timesheets table and one that is authorized_services. Here's a basic table structure for each:

```
TIMESHEETS                          AUTHORIZED_SERVICES
timesheet_id                        authorized_service_id
time_in (unix timestamp)            valid_from (unix timestamp)
time_out (unix timestamp)           valid_until (unix_timestamp)
service_id (int)                    service_id (int)
service_date (unix timestamp)       number_of_units (int)
```

What I need is to query the timesheets table to retrieve all results between a specified date range where the sum of the time_out - time_in / 60 / 60 <= number_of_units. This is the query I've come up with, which returns all the timesheet entries that match the authorized services based on the service_id and time range:

```
SELECT
((a.time_out - a.time_in)/60/60) as total_time,
a.service_id,
b.number_of_units,
FROM
timesheets a
LEFT JOIN authorization_services b
ON a.service_id = b.service_id
WHERE 
a.time_in >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2013-03-25") AND a.time_out <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2013-04-30")
AND a.service_date BETWEEN b.valid_from AND b.valid_until
GROUP BY a.timesheet_id;
```

However, I'd like to be able to only return the timesheet entries where the total sum of the total_time in the result set is less than the number_of_units. Is this possible?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:
What I would do in PHP for this is to loop through the returned results and add up each row's total_time to the cumulative_total_time. When the cumulative_total_time is equal to or less than the number_of_units, I'd break out of the loop. NOt sure how, or if, this is possible in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is

`GROUP BY b.service_id`
`HAVING SUM((a.time_out - a.time_in)/60/60) <= b.number_of_units`
isn't it?

Comment: hHi Lucia - thanks for the response but that only gets me the total time that's less than the number_of_units on a per row basis, rather than getting all rows' cumulative time.

Comment: As I understand, then what you need is a `GROUP BY b.service_id`, right? With this you would be able to get the cumulative sum by service_id. I am not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: That's what I thought too but then I'm missing each individual timesheet row. I don't think it's possible. Thanks for the ideas and help!

Comment: I don't think it is possible because you are in a different aggregation level. But, as I am not completely sure this is impossible, I would recommend you to ask this in a different question, just to know if it is possible to project in a query fields in a different aggregation level. Then it may also be a good idea to include your example too, to make it more understandable. It is only my opinion, just that I would ask it :)